# jQuery datepicker is not closing after select date in IE 10 and below

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, datepicker

ASP.NET 3.5 / jQuery 1.9.1 / jQuery UI 1.10.4

I have got jquery datepicker on a page and found an issue in IE10 and below versions that datepicker popup is not closing after select date.

Comment: Could you please provide jsfiddle?

Comment: If you're worried about cross-browser compatibility for things like older versions of IE, you should look into [webshims](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/)

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue with IE11 for my java Project. Did any one got any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to use like

```
.datepicker({autoclose: true});
```

when you enter date picker